# Progress bar in OPC not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

The progress bar in my shop is not updating the address data and so on. I debugged the code and the problem is this line in progress.phtml:

```
<?php if($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('billing', 'complete')): ?>
```

This is never true, even though, I am completing the OPC steps. What could be the reason. There are no errors in the logs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in *app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php* on line 351 it should be set to true, so it returns before it gets there, there are errors which are returned to its parent function.

This is called by the by the onepage controller and it will return it in a json format.

You should start by opening the error console and see the result of the xhr request in the network tab. It should give more insights about what is happening.